# SQL FUNCTION LIKE SEARCH ISSUE

Tags: sql-server, wildcard, temp-tables, sql-function

please help to fix my sql function!

in my sql function i have one temporary tables

parameter passing to function @searchstring  ---- "'%carrots%' AND tmp.ItemDescription like '%baby%'"

```
Declare  @tempvalues table  (itemdescription nvarchar(max))

@tempvalues  VALUES

-----------------------

CARROTS, BABY, CLASS I, FRESH
CARROTS, BABY, FROZEN
CARROTS, CLASS I, FRESH

------------------
```

so in function iam passing value for searching data using like query and if matches i need to insert  data in another table
like

in below temptable if its matching i need to insert 1 as corresponding line

```
Declare  @tempfinal table  (itemdescription nvarchar(max),matchcontains int)

**insert into @tempfinal select ItemDescription,'1'as matchcontains  from  @tempvalues tmp where tmp.ItemDescription like @searchstring**
```

but nothing is inserting in @tempfinal

**i need to search all words match**

please help to find a solution

**SAMPLE FUNCTION**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UDF_PredictItems_testfreetextdemo  
(  
 @FTSExpression    NVARCHAR(4000) 
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE   
(

  itemdescription  NVARCHAR(4000),
  matchcontains int

)  
AS  
BEGIN           
 Declare  @tempvalues table  (itemdescription nvarchar(max))                    
 insert into @tempvalues values ('CARROTS, BABY, CLASS I, FRESH') ,
 ('CARROTS, BABY, FROZEN 2.5 KGS') ,
 ('CAKE, CARROT, FROZEN 1 KGS') ,
 ('CARROTS, CLASS I, FRESH')  


 declare @containExpression nvarchar(max)
 set @containExpression =replace(replace(replace(@FTSExpression,' ','<>'),'><',''),'<>',' ') 
 set @containExpression=(Select  replace(@FTSExpression, ' ', '%'))   
 set @containExpression=(Select  replace(@containExpression, ' ', ' AND tmp.ItemDescription like ')) 
 set @containExpression=(select '''%'+@containExpression+'%''')  




  declare @tempfinal table(ItemDescription nvarchar(max),matchcontains int)      
  insert into @tempfinal select ItemDescription,CAST('1' AS INT) as matchcontains  from  @tempvalues tmp where tmp.ItemDescription like @containExpression    

   insert into @Result ( itemdescription,matchcontains )           
   select  itemdescription,0 from @tempfinal

   return;
   END
```

**CALLING FUNCTION**

```
SELECT * from UDF_PredictItems_testfreetextdemo('Carrots baby')
```

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server` ?

Comment: yes iam using SQL SERVER

Comment: Could you pls give me your code to [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18) ?

Comment: I've checked and it works fine for me. https://ibb.co/rMCBMqh

Comment: i added my sample function in my question, can you please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked and `LIKE` operator as you described that works fine for me.

```
Declare  @tempvalues table  (itemdescription nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO @tempvalues  
VALUES ('CARROTS'), ('BABY'), ('CLASS I'), ('FRESH'),('CARROTSI'), ('BABYI'), ('FROZENI'), ('CARROTSI'), ('CLASS I'), ('FRESH')

DECLARE @searchstring NVARCHAR(50) = '%carrots%'
SELECT * FROM @tempvalues WHERE itemdescription LIKE @searchstring
```

Output:

> CARROTS
>
> CARROTSI
>
> CARROTSI

Check my result [here](https://ibb.co/rMCBMqh)

**Updated**

So the problem not in `LIKE` operator, As @Antonios Katopodis's answer, you should insert `int` instead of `varchar` type

**Updated after fixing**

Your problem here

```
set @containExpression=(select '''%'+@containExpression+'%''')
```

You should fix by this way

```
set @containExpression=(select '%'+@containExpression+'%')
```

[image: Check my out put here]

Comment: like search is working query/newquery window but if i create function then its not working

Comment: I've fixed, Your problem here 

`set @containExpression=(select '%'+@containExpression+'%') ` instead of `set @containExpression=(select '''%'+@containExpression+'%''')  `

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
its worked partially ,..

still some issues
if i changed the parameter to " baby carrot " result is empty

Comment: Actually its 2000+ line function,
As you mentioned i changed the query

then its working for "carrots baby" but if i pass "baby carrots" result is empty
i need same result for  "baby carrots"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205143/discussion-between-samir-and-anonymous).

Comment: Basically, "LIKE" operator check the value whether it match or not. For example: your text "abcd", you Like '%bc%', it works because it ignore the first and end text, as long as it find "bc" match with where clause

Answer (score 0):

Your query is

```
INSERT INTO @tempfinal
SELECT 
   ItemDescription,
  '1' as matchcontains
FROM @tempvalues tmp
WHERE tmp.ItemDescription like @searchstring**
```

The problem with this is that you try to insert a char into an int field.
So try this:

```
INSERT INTO @tempfinal
SELECT 
   ItemDescription,
  CAST('1' AS INT) as matchcontains
FROM @tempvalues tmp
WHERE tmp.ItemDescription like @searchstring**
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO @tempfinal
SELECT 
   ItemDescription,
  1 as matchcontains
FROM @tempvalues tmp
WHERE tmp.ItemDescription like @searchstring**
```

Comment: i tried but not working, problem is if i pass two words  " carrots baby " then its not working